# Как сделать снимок экрана на Android без root?

Tags: android

Мне нужно сделать скриншот любого приложения на Android программно. Как можно это сделать не рутуя телефон?

Answer (score 2):

Без рута этого сделать нельзя. Причина - нарушение безопасности. Любая программа в фоне могла бы делать скриншоты и отправлять злоумышленикам. Оно вам нужно ;)?

Comment: В Android 4 такая возможность не появилась?

Comment: Нет. Не видел. Но в нем вроде интегрировали возможность делать скрины нажатием кнопок. Может просто попросить пользователя нажать их, а потом забрать скрин?

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какая модель телефона. Например, у меня Sony Ericsson, и на нем можно сделать снимки экрана через встроенную функцию. И при этом никаких root прав не просит. Но вы можете, как говорится, получить root права. Для этого существуют много сторонних программ.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку, устройства на Android выпускаются множеством производителей, общего способа сделать скриншот не существует.

Однако, в большинстве устройств (а в новых моделях и подавно во всех), предусмотрена функция получения скриншота посредством сочетания клавиш. Самое распространенное сочетание - кнопка включения и уменьшения громкости — это работает на большинстве (не на всех) смартфонов и планшетов LG, Sony, HTC, Lenovo, Xiaomi, Motorola, Nexus и многих других. Например, на моем Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 сочетание - кнопка уменьшения громкости и кнопка "открытых приложений".

Список возможных сочетаний:

- Android 3.2 и позднее — долгое нажатие на кнопку «Недавние
  программы».
- Android 4.0 — кнопка уменьшения громкости + кнопка «Включение».
- Samsung Galaxy — кнопка Назад + Домой (сохраняются в папке ScreenCapture).
- Samsung Galaxy S II — кнопка Домой + Блокировка (сохраняются в папке ScreenCapture).
- HTC Desire S — кнопка Включения + Домой (сохраняются в папку с фото).
- Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc S — кнопка уменьшения громкости + Включение.

В итоге: **универсального способа нет**. Надо гуглить сочетание клавиш конкретной модели. Также многие используют кастомные прошивки, а в них, как правило, есть предустановленная программа для снимков экрана.